MongoDB service automatically stope we need to start manually? What is the resone of that
MongoDB service automatically stope we need to start manually? What is the reasone of that

With the info supplied here there is no question to answer. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask will give you info on how to make a good question that might get an answer.

Check the MongoDB logs and add some information from the logs to your question. These logs will typically contain error messages that can provide clues about why the service stopped.
